# Uncaught ReferenceError: (function) is not defined

Tags: javascript

I just think this is useful for people having this problem:

I had this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css" type="text/css"/>
    <title>CSS TESTS</title>
    <script language="text/javascript">
        var move = 0;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="shape" onchange="alert(move);"/>
</body>
</html>
```

But I couldn't get the alert to work. I would get the Uncaught ReferenceError: move is not defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the **language** attribute on the script tag did not allow me to specify *text/javascript* but only javascript. The **type** attribute allows "*text/javascript*". That was all and I spent hours trying to find the bug in the javascript code... arg!

So, basically I changed the line that said

```
<script language="text/javascript">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and it all worked.

Comment: Better you remove it completely: `<script>...</script>`. That works fine in HTML5 and probably also browsers that don't understand HTML5.

Comment: Oh man thanks you so much :) :) :) You save my more hours. I have spent 2 hours in it :(

Answer (score 3):

Change `<script language="text/javascript">`  TO `<script type="text/javascript">`

Working Code --

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css" type="text/css"/>
    <title>CSS TESTS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var move = 0;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="shape" onchange="alert(move);"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

or do this, here "move" casted as string

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css" type="text/css"/>
    <title>CSS TESTS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="shape" onchange="alert('move');"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to include ,

```
 <script src="jquery-1.xx.x.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

if you are using jquery, xx-x stand for the version you are using.